# Different breakpoints for two navbars

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Is it possible to make the values at which the navbar changes to the collapsed version (smaller screen size) different for two menus on the same page? So, say an account menu with a few items to change when the window width gets bellow 800px, and the main menu to change at something like 600px.

I haven't included any code as the question is pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Give them each IDs and set up your media queries to suit.

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    #navbarOne { ... }
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
    #navbarTwo { ... }
}
```